# $f\in H^{1}$ and g is smooth and increasing, show that $g\circ f\in L^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

This is homework so no answers please

change was made (I forgot add that $Df\in L^{2}$)

We have compactly supported $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and weak derivative $Df\in L^{2}$ and smooth $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'\geq 0$. Denote the compact support by U. I want to show that

$\int_{U}|g\circ f|^{2}dx<\infty$

So even for this changed version, there is a counterexample. I think $f=loglog(1-\frac{1}{|x|})$ and $g=e^{e^{x}}-e$ over $B(0,1)$ will do but I will be interested to see some simpler counterexamples.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is true. What if $g$ grows so fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to make this a hint:

Take $f(x) = \begin{cases} {1 \over \sqrt[3]{x}}, & x \in (0,1) \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $g(x) = x^3$.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that it's weak derivative is also in L^{2}. But I will accept your example anyhow.